# Passing props to a component to use in testing a SnapShot

Tags: react-native, jestjs, react-navigation, react-test-renderer

Screen-test.js

```
it('renders the Engagement Detail modal', () => {
    const tree = renderer.create(<EngagementDetailModal details={engagementData}/>).toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
})
```

the component I am trying to test

```
class CompanyDetailView extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const data = this.props.navigation.getParam('details');

        return (
            // rest of the code
        )
    }
}
```

My data variable is just a bunch of static data. Using jest I am getting this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getParam' of undefined` and it is pointing to this line `const data = this.props.navigation.getParam('details');`
I know the component works as i run the app, just the test is failing.

I thought that by just providing the prop to the component in my Screen-test.js file it would work the same but i get undefined. How can i test this?

Also I am passing the prop using react navigation like this `onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('EngagementDetailModal', {details: this.props.data})`

Answer (score 0):

It cannot read the property `getParam`of navigation because you haven't mocked the navigation. So when the test case runs, it doesn't know what `this.props.navigation` does.
Add the following after imports section in your **Screen-test.js** .

```
 const testProps = props => ({

  navigation: {navigate: jest.fn(), getParam : jest.fn()},
  ...props,
})
```

Hope this helps!!